# Join two tables and combine the same fields using another field in one table and remaining fields as it is

Tags: sql-server, join, case

I have two tables (`table1` and `table2`), both have one column in common (`field1`). I need to join both tables. Then name the `field1` contents with a another column contents (`field2`)in `table1` and remaining `table2` contents as it is.

Table1:

```
Field1     Field2
------------------
 cat        pet1
 dog        pet2
 camel      pet3
```

Table2:

```
field1
--------
cat
dog
camel
lion
tiger
wolf
```

My output should be

```
Field1 
------------
pet1
pet2
pet3
lion
tiger
wolf
```

Comment: what You do? Show attempst

Comment: and show table as its structure, not 'free story'

Comment: the narration which i gave is to make it understandable to others .

Comment: this is a part of the problem which i am attempting which is far complicated to explain all the problem so posted only a part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this -

```
 Select field2 from table1 where field1
    In (select field1 from table2)
    Union 
    Select field1 from table1 where 
    Field1 not in (select field1 from table2)
    Union
    Select field1 from table2 where 
    Field1 not in (select field1 from table1);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23ae51/3)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Temp table variable to store join query result & interchange the temp table data with field1 as below :

```
insert into temp
select t2.field1, t1.field2 from
(
  select * from table2
)t2
left join table1 t1 on t1.field1 = t2.field1
update temp set field1 = filed 
where field1 in ('cat', 'dog', 'camel')
select field1 from temp
```

Comment: it is a good solution but the columns contents should not be updated they should be aliased with the other column contents using the `select` statement. `case when field1 in table1 then field2 else field1` (remainingvalues in table2)`end`

Comment: you have to just update the column value only in temp variable table not in regular table.

Comment: @YogeshSharma any custom hardcode is too bad. What if you have `where field1 in ('cat', 'dog', 'camel')` thousands of values? Not this way.

Comment: @AliaksandrBortnik just use select statement in field1

Answer (score 0):

Description is unclear, but I suppose it is so.

```
SELECT T2.Field1 as Data
FROM Table2 as T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 as T1
    ON T1.Field1 = T2.Field2
WHERE T1.Field1 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Field2 as Data 
FROM Table1;
```